# MS Graph Guest user cannot read Azure AD data

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azureportal

I created an application registered in [Application registration portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) and granted the admin consent there. As a user from our Azure AD, I can use my web app to read e.g. groups I have been assigned to in AD.

But when I invite a MS user to our AD (he becomes a Guest user there) the user can sign in into the application but he cannot read the groups (used the same method like the internal user). I always get an error: "*Authorization_RequestDenied Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.*"

Is there a way to get it work? I have tried to browse through the Azure portal to check permissions or whatever but nothing helped so far.

Comment: User settings -> External collaboration settings -> Check if "Guest user permissions are limited" is checked. That blocks user enumeration by guests. Make sure you want to allow it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, for both AAD Graph API and Microsoft graph api , you cannot use a MS account guest user to read the groups data like a member in that tenant.

Even you can set `guest user permissions with no limitation`, but you still cannot get the data of a group in that tenant. This is because that MS Account is not a member of that tanant. So, it cannot specify a tenant to query.

I suggest you can use/create a member in your tenant to achieve this.

Comment: All right, I did some checks. When I used the specific tenant (domain onmicrosoft.com) in the sign-in URL, I could sign-in and read the tenant data when logged in with MS account that was from another company (added as a guest into the tenant). But I could not sign-in with a personal account into the application at all. When I use "common" as a tenant, I can sign-in to the application with any kind of MS account, but I cannot access the specific tenant data. I guess there is no workaround?

Comment: Hi @Ondrej, Right, there is no workaround with guest user( MS account ). So, I suggest you use the member(internal account) to approach that. Using Guest user to get the directory data doesn't make scense actually. :-)

Comment: Hi @Ondrej , If this answer is helpful, you can accept it as answer so that we can help more people. Thanks!